# Performance of ThreadLocal variable

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, thread-local

How much is read from `ThreadLocal` variable slower than from regular field?

More concretely is simple object creation faster or slower than access to `ThreadLocal` variable?

I assume that it is fast enough so that having `ThreadLocal<MessageDigest>` instance is much faster then creating instance of `MessageDigest` every time. But does that also apply for byte[10] or byte[1000] for example?

Edit: Question is what is really going on when calling `ThreadLocal`'s get? If that is just a field, like any other, then answer would be "it's always fastest", right?

Comment: A thread local is bascally a field containing a hashmap and a lookup where the key is the current thread object. It is therefore much slower but still fast. :)

Comment: @eckes: it certainly behaves like that, but it's not usually implemented this way. Instead, `Thread`s contain a (unsynchronized) hashmap where the key is the current `ThreadLocal` object

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Running unpublished benchmarks, `ThreadLocal.get` takes around 35 cycle per iteration on my machine. Not a great deal. In Sun's implementation a custom linear probing hash map in `Thread` maps `ThreadLocal`s to values. Because it is only ever accessed by a single thread, it can be very fast.

Allocation of small objects take a similar number of cycles, although because of cache exhaustion you may get somewhat lower figures in a tight loop.

Construction of `MessageDigest` is likely to be relatively expensive. It has a fair amount of state and construction goes through the `Provider` SPI mechanism. You may be able to optimise by, for instance, cloning or providing the `Provider`.

Just because it may be faster to cache in a `ThreadLocal` rather than create does not necessarily mean that the system performance will increase. You will have additional overheads related to GC which slows everything down.

Unless your application very heavily uses `MessageDigest` you might want to consider using a conventional thread-safe cache instead.

Comment: IMHO, the fastest way is just to ignore the SPI and use something like `new org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.SHA1Digest()`. I'm quite sure no cache can beat it.

Comment: I suppose thread local is anyway has to deal with TLS memory access which means CPU cache reset, so it has dramatic influence on overall machine performance

Answer (score 65):

In 2009, some JVMs implemented `ThreadLocal` using an unsynchronised `HashMap` in the `Thread.currentThread()` object. This made it extremely fast (though not nearly as fast as using a regular field access, of course), as well as ensuring that the `ThreadLocal` object got tidied up when the `Thread` died. Updating this answer in 2016, it seems most (all?) newer JVMs use a `ThreadLocalMap` with linear probing. I am uncertain about the performance of those – but I cannot imagine it is significantly worse than the earlier implementation.

Of course, `new Object()` is also very fast these days, and the garbage collectors are also very good at reclaiming short-lived objects.

Unless you are certain that object creation is going to be expensive, or you need to persist some state on a thread by thread basis, you are better off going for the simpler allocate when needed solution, and only switching over to a `ThreadLocal` implementation when a profiler tells you that you need to.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer to actually address the question.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a modern JVM that doesn't use linear probing for ThreadLocalMap? Java 8 OpenJDK still seems to be using ThreadLocalMap with linear probing. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java#297

Comment: @Karthick Sorry no I can't. I wrote this back in 2009. I will update.

Answer (score 37):

Good question, I've been asking myself that recently. To give you definite numbers, the benchmarks below (in Scala, compiled to virtually the same bytecodes as the equivalent Java code):

```
var cnt: String = ""
val tlocal = new java.lang.ThreadLocal[String] {
  override def initialValue = ""
}

def loop_heap_write = {                                                                                                                           
  var i = 0                                                                                                                                       
  val until = totalwork / threadnum                                                                                                               
  while (i < until) {                                                                                                                             
    if (cnt ne "") cnt = "!"                                                                                                                      
    i += 1                                                                                                                                        
  }                                                                                                                                               
  cnt                                                                                                                                          
} 

def threadlocal = {
  var i = 0
  val until = totalwork / threadnum
  while (i < until) {
    if (tlocal.get eq null) i = until + i + 1
    i += 1
  }
  if (i > until) println("thread local value was null " + i)
}
```

available [here](https://github.com/axel22/threads/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/threads/ParallelTests.scala), were performed on an AMD 4x 2.8 GHz dual-cores and a quad-core i7 with hyperthreading (2.67 GHz).

These are the numbers:

### i7

**Specs: Intel i7 2x quad-core @ 2.67 GHz
Test: scala.threads.ParallelTests**

**Test name: loop_heap_read**

Thread num.: 1
Total tests: 200

Run times:  (showing last 5)
 9.0069       9.0036       9.0017       9.0084       9.0074      (avg = 9.1034       min = 8.9986       max = 21.0306     )

Thread num.: 2
Total tests: 200

Run times:  (showing last 5)
 4.5563       4.7128       4.5663       4.5617       4.5724      (avg = 4.6337       min = 4.5509       max = 13.9476     )

Thread num.: 4
Total tests: 200

Run times:  (showing last 5)
 2.3946       2.3979       2.3934       2.3937       2.3964      (avg = 2.5113       min = 2.3884       max = 13.5496     )

Thread num.: 8
Total tests: 200

Run times:  (showing last 5)
 2.4479       2.4362       2.4323       2.4472       2.4383      (avg = 2.5562       min = 2.4166       max = 10.3726     )

**Test name:   threadlocal**

Thread num.: 1
Total tests: 200

Run times:  (showing last 5)
 91.1741      90.8978      90.6181      90.6200      90.6113     (avg = 91.0291      min = 90.6000      max = 129.7501    )

Thread num.: 2
Total tests: 200

Run times:  (showing last 5)
 45.3838      45.3858      45.6676      45.3772      45.3839     (avg = 46.0555      min = 45.3726      max = 90.7108     )

Thread num.: 4
Total tests: 200

Run times:  (showing last 5)
 22.8118      22.8135      59.1753      22.8229      22.8172     (avg = 23.9752      min = 22.7951      max = 59.1753     )

Thread num.: 8
Total tests: 200

Run times:  (showing last 5)
 22.2965      22.2415      22.3438      22.3109      22.4460     (avg = 23.2676      min = 22.2346      max = 50.3583     )

### AMD

**Specs: AMD 8220 4x dual-core @ 2.8 GHz
Test: scala.threads.ParallelTests**

**Test name:   loop_heap_read**

Total work:  20000000
Thread num.: 1
Total tests: 200

Run times:  (showing last 5)
 12.625       12.631       12.634       12.632       12.628      (avg = 12.7333      min = 12.619       max = 26.698      )

Test name:   loop_heap_read
Total work:  20000000

Run times:  (showing last 5)
 6.412        6.424        6.408        6.397        6.43        (avg = 6.5367       min = 6.393        max = 19.716      )

Thread num.: 4
Total tests: 200

Run times:  (showing last 5)
 3.385        4.298        9.7          6.535        3.385       (avg = 5.6079       min = 3.354        max = 21.603      )

Thread num.: 8
Total tests: 200

Run times:  (showing last 5)
 5.389        5.795        10.818       3.823        3.824       (avg = 5.5810       min = 2.405        max = 19.755      )

**Test name:   threadlocal**

Thread num.: 1
Total tests: 200

Run times:  (showing last 5)
 200.217      207.335      200.241      207.342      200.23      (avg = 202.2424     min = 200.184      max = 245.369     )

Thread num.: 2
Total tests: 200

Run times:  (showing last 5)
 100.208      100.199      100.211      103.781      100.215     (avg = 102.2238     min = 100.192      max = 129.505     )

Thread num.: 4
Total tests: 200

Run times:  (showing last 5)
 62.101       67.629       62.087       52.021       55.766      (avg = 65.6361      min = 50.282       max = 167.433     )

Thread num.: 8
Total tests: 200

Run times:  (showing last 5)
 40.672       74.301       34.434       41.549       28.119      (avg = 54.7701      min = 28.119       max = 94.424      )

### Summary

A thread local is around 10-20x that of the heap read. It also seems to scale well on this JVM implementation and these architectures with the number of processors.

Comment: +1 Kudos on being the only one to give quantitative results.  I'm a bit skeptical because these tests are in Scala, but like you said, the Java bytecodes should be similar...

Comment: Thanks! This while loop results in virtually the same bytecode as the corresponding Java code would produce. Different times could be observed on different VMs, though - this has been tested on a Sun JVM1.6.

Comment: This benchmark code does not simulate a good use case for ThreadLocal. In the first method: every thread will have a shared representation in memory, the string does not change. In the second method you benchmark the cost of a hashtable lookup where the string is disjunctive between all threads.

Comment: The string does not change, but it's read from memory (the write of `"!"` never occurs) in the first method - the first method is effectively equivalent to subclassing `Thread` and giving it a custom field. The benchmark measures an extreme edge case where the entire computation consists of reading a variable/thread local - real applications may not be affected depending on their access pattern, but in the worst case, they will behave as above.

Answer (score 3):

@Pete is correct test before you optimise.

I would be very surprised if constructing a MessageDigest has any serious overhead when compared to actaully using it.

Miss using ThreadLocal can be a source of leaks and dangling references, that don't have a clear life cycle, generally I don't ever use ThreadLocal without a very clear plan of when a particular resource will be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Here it goes another test. The results shows that ThreadLocal is a bit slower than a regular field, but in the same order. Aprox 12% slower

```
public class Test {
private static final int N = 100000000;
private static int fieldExecTime = 0;
private static int threadLocalExecTime = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    int execs = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < execs; i++) {
        new FieldExample().run(i);
        new ThreadLocaldExample().run(i);
    }
    System.out.println("Field avg:"+(fieldExecTime / execs));
    System.out.println("ThreadLocal avg:"+(threadLocalExecTime / execs));
}

private static class FieldExample {
    private Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void run(int z) {
        System.out.println(z+"-Running  field sample");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            String s = Integer.toString(i);
            map.put(s,"a");
            map.remove(s);
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long t = (end - start);
        fieldExecTime += t;
        System.out.println(z+"-End field sample:"+t);
    }
}

private static class ThreadLocaldExample{
    private ThreadLocal<Map<String,String>> myThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Map<String,String>>() {
        @Override protected Map<String, String> initialValue() {
            return new HashMap<String, String>();
        }
    };

    public void run(int z) {
        System.out.println(z+"-Running thread local sample");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            String s = Integer.toString(i);
            myThreadLocal.get().put(s, "a");
            myThreadLocal.get().remove(s);
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long t = (end - start);
        threadLocalExecTime += t;
        System.out.println(z+"-End thread local sample:"+t);
    }
}
}'
```

Output:

0-Running  field sample

0-End field sample:6044

0-Running thread local sample

0-End thread local sample:6015

1-Running  field sample

1-End field sample:5095

1-Running thread local sample

1-End thread local sample:5720

2-Running  field sample

2-End field sample:4842

2-Running thread local sample

2-End thread local sample:5835

3-Running  field sample

3-End field sample:4674

3-Running thread local sample

3-End thread local sample:5287

4-Running  field sample

4-End field sample:4849

4-Running thread local sample

4-End thread local sample:5309

5-Running  field sample

5-End field sample:4781

5-Running thread local sample

5-End thread local sample:5330

6-Running  field sample

6-End field sample:5294

6-Running thread local sample

6-End thread local sample:5511

7-Running  field sample

7-End field sample:5119

7-Running thread local sample

7-End thread local sample:5793

8-Running  field sample

8-End field sample:4977

8-Running thread local sample

8-End thread local sample:6374

9-Running  field sample

9-End field sample:4841

9-Running thread local sample

9-End thread local sample:5471

Field avg:5051

ThreadLocal avg:5664

Env:

openjdk version "1.8.0_131"

Intel® Core™ i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Sorry, this isn't even close to being a valid test. A) Biggest issue: you're allocating Strings with every iteration (`Int.toString)`, which is extremely expensive compared to what you're testing. B) you're doing two map ops every iteration, also totally unrelated and expensive. Try incrementing a primitive int from ThreadLocal instead. C) Use `System.nanoTime` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis`, the former is for profiling, the latter is for _user_ date-time purposes and can change under your feet. D) You should avoid allocs entirely, including the top level ones for your "example" classes

Answer (score 0):

Build it and measure it.

Also, you only need one threadlocal if you encapsulate your message digesting behaviour into an object. If you need a local MessageDigest and a local byte[1000] for some purpose, create an object with a messageDigest and a byte[] field and put that object into the ThreadLocal rather than both individually.

Comment: Thanks, MessageDigest and byte[] are different uses, so one object isn't needed.