# Get UserDetails object from Security Context in Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security 3 and Spring MVC 3.05.

I would like to print username of currently logged in user,how can I fetch UserDetails in my Controller?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView indexView(){
         UserDetails user = ?
                mv.addObject("username", user.getUsername());
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        return mv;
    }
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

If you already know for sure that the user is logged in (in your example if `/index.html` is protected):

```
UserDetails userDetails =
 (UserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

To first check if the user is logged in, check that the current `Authentication` is not a `AnonymousAuthenticationToken`.

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
        // userDetails = auth.getPrincipal()
}
```

Comment: this gives me an exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails`

Comment: I use UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken for my authentication, and that returns a String even for a logged in user. The object returned may vary depending on the type of Authentication used; cast your class as appropriate, for me it is String.

Comment: I believe this is not the best method due to SecurityContextHolder using ThreadLocal underneath  (see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609826/performance-of-threadlocal-variable ). Unless someone could provide some actual benchmark for this method (because there are also other strategies than simple ThreadLocal, but I have not tested them) I'd advise going with Farm's answer instead.

Comment: If principal is String, you can use SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails().
It works at least for Spring Security Saml this way.

Answer (score 34):

Let Spring 3 injection take care of this.

Thanks to [tsunade21](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5351828/286588) the easiest way is:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)   
 public ModelAndView anyMethodNameGoesHere(Principal principal) {
        final String loggedInUserName = principal.getName();

 }
```

Comment: Amazing. Makes testing much easier than when using static methods on SecurityContextHolder.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to print user name on the pages, maybe you'll like this solution. It's free from object castings and works without Spring Security too:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView indexView(HttpServletRequest request) {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");

    String userName = "not logged in"; // Any default user  name
    Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
    if (principal != null) {
        userName = principal.getName();
    }

    mv.addObject("username", userName);

    // By adding a little code (same way) you can check if user has any
    // roles you need, for example:

    boolean fAdmin = request.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
    mv.addObject("isAdmin", fAdmin);

    return mv;
}
```

Note "**HttpServletRequest request**" parameter added.

Works fine because Spring injects it's own objects (wrappers) for HttpServletRequest, Principal etc., so you can use standard java methods to retrieve user information.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using spring security then you can get the current logged in user by

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
     String name = auth.getName(); //get logged in username
```

Answer (score 1):

That's another solution (Spring Security 3):

```
public String getLoggedUser() throws Exception {
    String name = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    return (!name.equals("anonymousUser")) ? name : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to find out principal (user email who logged in)

```
  org.opensaml.saml2.core.impl.NameIDImpl principal =  
  (NameIDImpl) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

  String email = principal.getValue();
```

This code is written on top of SAML.