# Adding new attributes to the Spring MVC Session

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my project, I am using spring security. To get the current username I am accessing SpringContextHolder

```
UserDetails principal = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
username = principal.getUsername()
```

Using `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` object I can only retrieve limited information like username, password, roles etc. What if I want to retrieve user id? Do I need to make database call every time to get more user details corresponding to the username? Can't I set attributes to the session object? In most of the post, solution is proposed by using `ModelAndView` object. But In my case, I don't need SessionAttributes for the view layer but also requires at business logic layer.

Mainly I want to persist UserID and ClientID in some way to access whenever and wherever required.

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom UserDetails and UserDetailsService

[Spring Security: custom userdetails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607696/spring-security-custom-userdetails)

[Custom UserDetailsService example for spring 3 security](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/16/custom-userdetailsservice-example-for-spring-3-security/)