# Spring Security Additional Logged in user information

Tags: spring, security

I have created a Spring security application. When the user logs in the user name and roles get stored in Security Context. The same can be retrieved using Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

How can I store the additional user information like user ID, Email, Associated Branch ID etc in the context?

Comment: Do you use a `UserDetailsService` to load the user from database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Security: custom userdetails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607696/spring-security-custom-userdetails)

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to implement a custom [`UserDetails`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html). You can read
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607696/spring-security-custom-userdetails%20for%20more%20details) for a longer explanation.