# spring security cache control headers not visible after upgrade from spring-security 3.1.0.RELEASE to 4.1.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-security

[spring-security cache-control headers missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787921/spring-security-cache-control-headers-missing)
Experiencing same problem as mentioned in above post. Can anyone help with it?

I recently upgraded my application from spring 3.1.2.RELEASE to 4.2.6.RELEASE and spring-security 3.1.0.RELEASE to 4.1.0.RELEASE

But when testing the upgraded application on the application server it seems that the http cache-control response headers are gone.

Before the upgrade these cache headers were found for both html en json requests:

Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache

After the upgrade

only this header exist for html requests:

Cache-Control: no-store
and no headers for the json requests

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get UserDetails object from Security Context in Spring MVC controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161985/get-userdetails-object-from-security-context-in-spring-mvc-controller)

Comment: upgraded my application from spring 3.1.2.RELEASE to 4.2.6.RELEASE and spring-security 3.1.0.RELEASE to 4.1.0.RELEASE

But when testing the upgraded application on the application server it seems that the http cache-control response headers are gone.