# Spring security oauth2 , get userdetails object from SecurityContext

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

I have a traditional Oauth2 setup for my micro services. When i try to use

```
CustomUserDetails principal = (CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

It always gives me ClassCastException string can not cast to CustomUserDetails. `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` is always string , i.e : my username.

Please help if any one solved this problem.

Comment: Can you show how  you have defined your custom UserDetailService please ?

Comment: Seems like it’s duplicate of the following questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161985/get-userdetails-object-from-security-context-in-spring-mvc-controller