# How to use an index variable in a recursion?

Tags: java, variables, recursion, indexing

I want to use an index variable inside a recursion, without sending it as a parameter when calling the function. However, if I reset it at the beginning (e.g i = 0), it will reset on every run. I want to use it as a counter (to count the function runs).

Comment: As long as you promise to reset it when you call the top-level function, you could implement your counter as a static variable. See http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-static-variable-methods.html

Comment: I want to count how many times the function called itself, in order to know when to stop and return a value. I usually send the function '0' as an int parameter and just ++ it every time, but I would like to find an alternative more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: So the index is the stop condition? Then I think you should pass it as a parameter, then inside the method decrease by one if it is greater than zero, and pass it again, until the value the function receives is zero.  Is that what you are doing now?

Comment: Oh your are increasing instead. It's the same. I don't know a more elegant way. Maybe someone else does.

Comment: If you are using the index to access a list maybe you can pass the list with one less element, until it is empty.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm doing, but I figured using less parameters for achieving the same result is more elegant.

Comment: It isn't more elegant, if you have to use an instance variable, an attribute instead, and lose the possibility to use it in a multi threaded environment. Au contraire!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you will obviously want to initialize it only once. A common pattern in recursion is:

```
public void run(int opt) {
  run_helper(opt, 0);
}

private void run(int opt, int depth) {
  if (whatever) { run(opt, depth + 1); }
}
```

Where the outer method does nothing but some initialization.

A "solution" you will see suggested often (e.g. in the first comment to your question) will be to use static variables. This approach is a bad style, and will cause your program to fail in various weird way once you add multi-threading (e.g. by making a UI version, or run it in multithreading web server). And the worst is that it may at first appear to work, and only start misbehaving subtly when there are many users. **So keep away from "static" for everything except constants!**

With "static" it would commonly look like this:

```
static int counter;

public void start() {
  counter = 0;
  recurse();
}

public void recurse() {
  counter += 1;
  if (whatever) { recurse(); }
}
```

Now imagine that two users invoke `start` at the same time. **They will overwrite each others counter!** Because static means, it's shared amongst threads and users.

Here is a **really simple to understand solution**:

```
class MyTask {
  int counter = 0;

  public void recurse() {
    counter++;
    if (whatever) { recurse(); }
  }

  public int getIterations() {
    return counter;
  }
}

public void run() {
  MyTask task = new MyTask();
  task.run();
  System.out.println("Task took "+task.getIterations()+" itertions.");
}
```

You then create a task, run it, and retrieve the counter at the end. Clean, dead simple, efficient and reliable. **If you have more than one thread/user, each will have a separate MyTask object, and you won't run into any problem.**

Plus, you can add additional statistics, and they are all cleanly wrapped in the task object. "Average time per iteration"? "Average recursion depth"? No problem. The task object can also be used to store your result.

The use of `ThreadLocal` has been suggested here. I do not agree with this. It offers no benefits of the task object at all. Just try to implement it with `ThreadLocal` and the task object and you'll see the difference. Plus, `ThreadLocal` is empirically 10x slower than accessing heap values (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4756605/1060350 ). For `int` it likely is even worse. So **never ever call `ThreadLocal#get` in a performance critical codepath**. If you intend to use `ThreadLocal`, use it outside of this codepath, and use a local variable (or a Task object) to feed the "local static" variable into your critical codepath.

Comment: why do you propose to have a static variable in the first place?

Comment: Because that is the common solution people come up with. It needs to be discussed, and the drawbacks need to be pointed out. In particular, since Eclipse likes to suggest making variables static to "fix" access errors.

Comment: I can't see why anyone would suggest to make this type of variable static though.

Comment: See the first comment posted on the question. It suggests using a static variable. And in fact, a static variable will work, as long as you are not reentrant or multithreaded. I.e. don't use a swing UI. That is usually when those static variables start failing on people, when they have an UI.

Comment: I just fail to see the benefit of sharing the variable among all instances of the class.

Comment: It's bound to break. That is well known. Search for "+static +java" on stackoverflow for a horror cabinet of misuses of static. But unless you tell them **why not to use static**, they'll use it because it appears to be the simplest solution to their problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate it using two methods: one public to start the recursive iterations and initialize the counter to zero, and another private one, that is where the recursive calls are made. This way every time you call the public method the counter gets initialized. It would be something like this (in java):

```
public class Recursion{
    private int iterations=0;

    private int calcFactorial(int n){
        iterations++;
        if (n==2)
            return 2;
        else
            return n * calcFactorial(n-1);
    }

    public int factorial(int n){
        //initialize the counter
        iterations = 0;
        return calcFactorial(n);
    }

    public int getIterations(){
        return iterations;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a simple parameter-based approach, given that the index is used as a stop condition. JavaScript implementation:

```
var recurse = function() {
    recurseHelper(0);
};

var recurseHelper = function(iteration) {
    // run for 100 iterations, 
    if (iterationCount > 100)
        return;

    // do stuff...


    recurseHelper(iteration + 1);
}
```

However, if you just want to invoke a function a certain number of times, why are you looking to use recursion in particular? You could just use a loop. Again in JavaScript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // do stuff...
}
```

Compilers can have more fun with unwinding loops than with recursion constructs, depending on the complexity of your recursion algorithm.

Comment: He probably doesn't have a *linear* recursion. There are plenty of non-linear problems like this. For example in an XML tree, find the first (in document order) 10 nodes at depth 3 or more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attribute, but why? Why not passing the value as parameter?

```
public class Empty {

    private int steps = 0;  

    public static void main (String args [])
    {
        Empty e = new Empty ();
        System.out.println (e.reverse ("This is a test"));
        System.out.println ("steps: " + e.steps);
    }

    public String reverse (String s) {
        ++steps;
        if (s.length () < 2) 
            return s;
        else return reverse (s.substring (1)) + s.charAt (0);
    }
}
```

From the comments I get, that you use it as counter, to detect when to end the recursion. That doesn't look very useful. Don't you have a condition which can be derived from the parameters, like list.length () or such?

Of course, calling the method twice will increase the counter further. You might reset it, if it isn't used by two thread concurrently, and a wrapped method in an inner object might help to prevent calling it without resetting the counter first.

But that is much more boilerplate than passing the counter around.

A parameter is a much cleaner solution for counting the invocations.

If you want to prevent stackoverflows while debugging, a curios alternative is to call a randomizer, and return in 1 of 10 000 cases.

Answer (score -1):

The most natural thing to do, is to have an auxilliary parameter as you describe in your post, especially if it is used to determine when to stop the recursion. If relying on a member variable you could have a helper method that resets the couter before calling the recursive method, and call the helper-method whenever you want to invoke the recursive function.

**If you prefer to stick with a single method** you'll have to do something like this:

Create a member variable called `insideMethod` which is set to false by default. When the method is called, it inspects this variable. If it is false, it is the first call, and the counter should be reset, otherwise the counter should just be incremented. After that, the `insideMethod` is set to true. Upon returning, the `insideMethod` should be set back to false, only if it was *this* invokation that set it to true.

Remember to make `insideMethod` and the index variables ThreadLocal.

Pseudo code:

```
ThreadLocal<Boolean> insideMethod = false
ThreadLocal<Integer> index = 0

....

void recMethod(args) {
    boolean topCall = (insideMethod == false)
    insideMethod = true

    if (topCall)
        index = 0
    else
        index++

    // Body of the method...

    if (topCall)
        insideMethod = false
}
```

Comment: `ThreadLocal<Integer>` will perform quite bad, because it requires creating a lot of `Integer` objects, thus putting quite a load on the garbage collection.

Comment: I'm smelling premature optimization.

Comment: There is a much simpler solution, see my reply. Wrap it into a task object.
I have really bad experiences with frequently changing wrapped native types in Java. It has killed performance in too many sitations for me to keep away from it wherever possible. At least, change it to a `Counter` object that isn't immutable.

In fact, I doubt that your code actually compiles. `index++` should not work on `ThreadLocal<Integer>` objects...

Comment: I said it was pseudo code. Saying that ThreadLocals will perform poorly is *completely ridiculus* when not knowing how the rest of the method is implemented. Creating a seperate task object is fairly ok, but is a bit counterintuitive. A regular method call may look cleaner.

Comment: If you'd go from simplified pseudocode to *real* code, it would be easy to see that ThreadLocal is not much more "intuitive" to use than just making a task object. In fact, it is pretty messy.