# thread local storage versus hashtable

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, thread-local

I have a singleton class and I need to store some fields that are specific to each thread. I am thinking about either adding those fields as ThreadLocal variables in the singleton or using a synchronized Hashtable with keys being the thread IDs. Any suggestions in terms of which one has a lower overhead? I saw a [performance comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609826/performance-of-threadlocal-variable) earlier but that isn't exactly what I need.

Comment: The fields are thread specific, but they may be accessed by other threads? IOW, why do you need to store them in a singleton class?

Answer (score 1):

`ThreadLocal` **is** essentially a `HashMap` keyed on the thread ID. You'd be better to use a `ThreadLocal`.

There's also (I believe) further optimisation going on behind the scenes for you with ThreadLocals.