# Performance impact on ThreadLocal operations

Tags: java, performance, thread-local

I already have a `ThreadLocal` object defined as a class `Context`

```
class Context {
.....
some existing fields
.....
}
ThreadLocal<Context> = .....
```

If I have to add a new boolean field to the above Context class, what would be the performance impact for `ThreadLocal` get() and set() operations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Performance of ThreadLocal variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609826/performance-of-threadlocal-variable)

Comment: None? Keep in mind that it's a reference to the actual object that is stored

Comment: Nil. The size or content of the object has nothing to do with the performance of storing a reference to it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `get` method of the `ThreadLocal` class looks like

```
    public T get() {
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        ThreadLocalMap map = getMap(t);
        if (map != null) {
            ThreadLocalMap.Entry e = map.getEntry(this);
        ...
```

So whenever we are getting an object from the ThreadLocal, it will get the element from its internally stored map.

Since the `get`/`set` method only needs to read/write the object in the map, adding/removing a field in the object's class won't have an effect on the performance.